# Angular Material Table

Tags: angular, angular-material, frontend, material-design, web-frontend

I learning Angular, and I am using call an API to receive data to populate my table.

The records of the table are not displaying. But using console.log I can see them in the console.

This is my component.ts

```
export class ListaUtentiComponent implements OnInit {

  displayedColumns =  ['id', 'username'];
  @Input()
  dataSource: MatTableDataSource<any>;

  utenti: Utenti [];
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;

  constructor(public rest: ApiService, private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource();
    this.getUser();
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
  }

 getUser() {
    this.rest.getUsers().subscribe((data) => {
      console.log(data);
      alert(data);
      this.dataSource['data']; 
      return data;


    });
  }
}
```

And this is my component.html

```
<div class="mat-elevation-z8">
  <table mat-table class="full-width-table" matSort aria-label="Elements" [dataSource]="dataSource">
    
<ng-container matColumnDef="id">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Id</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let ut">{{ut.id}}</td>
    </ng-container>

 
   <ng-container matColumnDef="username">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Nome</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let ut">{{ut.name}}</td>
    </ng-container> 

    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
  </table>

  <mat-paginator #paginator
      [length]="dataSource?.data.length"
      [pageIndex]="0"
      [pageSize]="10"
      [pageSizeOptions]="[10, 20]">
  </mat-paginator>
</div>
```

Please help me I don't know what is wrong.

Comment: Anytime subscribe is used, the code inside must tell angular of changes. ChangeDetectorRef detectChanges()

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any code that assigns fetched data to dataSource for the mat-table.

What you have to do is to update the dataSource, for example like this:

```
getUser() {
    this.rest.getUsers().subscribe((data) => {
      this.dataSource = data;
    });
}
```

Comment: I have used @angular/material: table to create the component now if I change the code, it responds with an error.

So I change the code on this component?
datasource.ts.

xS I'm so really sorry for my ignorance

Comment: don't be :) its okay :) 
maybe could you prepare a reproduction of the problem on Stackblitz? will be easier to understand the issue

Comment: I can't because I don't work with my pc, I can show you the file in the answer

Comment: Im not sure why you need this separate file, but it still looks like the only thing to fix is to update the data correctly inside your TS component

Answer (score 0):

```
import { DataSource } from '@angular/cdk/collections';
import { MatPaginator } from '@angular/material/paginator';
import { MatSort } from '@angular/material/sort';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Observable, of as observableOf, merge } from 'rxjs';

// TODO: Replace this with your own data model type
export interface ListaUtentiItem {
        id: string,
        email: string,
        emailConfirmed: boolean,
        passwordHash: string,
        securityStamp: string,
        phoneNumber: string,
        phoneNumberConfirmed: boolean,
        twoFactorEnabled: boolean,
        lockoutEndDateUtc: string,
        lockoutEnabled: boolean,
        accessFailedCount: number,
        userName:string
}

// TODO: replace this with real data from your application
const EXAMPLE_DATA: ListaUtentiItem[] = [
  // {id: 1, name: 'Hydrogen'},
  // {id: 2, name: 'Helium'},
  // {id: 3, name: 'Lithium'},
  // {id: 4, name: 'Beryllium'},
  // {id: 5, name: 'Boron'},
  // {id: 6, name: 'Carbon'},
  // {id: 7, name: 'Nitrogen'},
  // {id: 8, name: 'Oxygen'},
  // {id: 9, name: 'Fluorine'},
  // {id: 10, name: 'Neon'},
  // {id: 11, name: 'Sodium'},
  // {id: 12, name: 'Magnesium'},
  // {id: 13, name: 'Aluminum'},
  // {id: 14, name: 'Silicon'},
  // {id: 15, name: 'Phosphorus'},
  // {id: 16, name: 'Sulfur'},
  // {id: 17, name: 'Chlorine'},
  // {id: 18, name: 'Argon'},
  // {id: 19, name: 'Potassium'},
  // {id: '20', userName: 'Calcium',},
];

/**
 * Data source for the ListaUtenti view. This class should
 * encapsulate all logic for fetching and manipulating the displayed data
 * (including sorting, pagination, and filtering).
 */
export class ListaUtentiDataSource extends DataSource<ListaUtentiItem> {
  data: ListaUtentiItem[] = EXAMPLE_DATA;
  paginator: MatPaginator;
  sort: MatSort;

  constructor() {
   super();
  }

  /**
   * Connect this data source to the table. The table will only update when
   * the returned stream emits new items.
   * @returns A stream of the items to be rendered.
   */
  connect(): Observable<ListaUtentiItem[]> {
    // Combine everything that affects the rendered data into one update
    // stream for the data-table to consume.
    const dataMutations = [
      observableOf(this.data),
      this.paginator.page,
      this.sort.sortChange
    ];

    return merge(...dataMutations).pipe(map(() => {
      return this.getPagedData(this.getSortedData([...this.data]));
    }));
  }

  /**
   *  Called when the table is being destroyed. Use this function, to clean up
   * any open connections or free any held resources that were set up during connect.
   */
  disconnect() {}

  /**
   * Paginate the data (client-side). If you're using server-side pagination,
   * this would be replaced by requesting the appropriate data from the server.
   */
  private getPagedData(data: ListaUtentiItem[]) {
    const startIndex = this.paginator.pageIndex * this.paginator.pageSize;
    return data.splice(startIndex, this.paginator.pageSize);
  }

  /**
   * Sort the data (client-side). If you're using server-side sorting,
   * this would be replaced by requesting the appropriate data from the server.
   */
  private getSortedData(data: ListaUtentiItem[]) {
    if (!this.sort.active || this.sort.direction === '') {
      return data;
    }

    return data.sort((a, b) => {
      const isAsc = this.sort.direction === 'asc';
      switch (this.sort.active) {
        case 'username': return compare(a.userName, b.userName, isAsc);
        case 'id': return compare(+a.id, +b.id, isAsc);
        default: return 0;
      }
    });
  }
}

/** Simple sort comparator for example ID/Name columns (for client-side sorting). */
function compare(a: string | number, b: string | number, isAsc: boolean) {
  return (a < b ? -1 : 1) * (isAsc ? 1 : -1);
}
```

This is.